# How to query by id in many to many relationship in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have Group entity like

```
public class Group
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupTag> TagsLink { get; set; }
    }
```

I have Tag entity like

```
 public class Tag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupTag> GroupLink { get; set; }
    }
```

and I mapped

```
 public class GroupTag
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public Group Group { get; set; }
        public string TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
        public byte Order { get; set; }
    }
```

and so how to retrieve group by groupId and tag by tagId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using net core 5 or 6 you can add some more extension to your classes:

```
public class Group
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupTag> GroupTags { get; set; }
        
         public string CategoryId { get; set; }
          public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

         public  virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

 public class Tag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GroupTag> GroupTags { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

If you already created dbcontext you can get a group by groupId

```
var group= context.Groups
 .Include(i=> i.Tags) // if you don't need tags, ommit this
 .FirstOrDefault(i=> i.GroupId==groupId);
```

and the same way you can get a tag